# `tcpdump` shows different length for the same ARP packet

Tags: linux, tcpdump, arp

I'm running `tcpdump` in two identical Linux machines with this command:

```
tcpdump -i enp0s8 -nn -XX -vvv
```

During an ARP request in the sender machine I see:

```
20:03:29.113813 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.0.0.1 tell 10.0.0.2, length 28
0x0000:  0800 27bb f251 0800 27cf ce8e 0806 0001  ..'..Q..'.......
0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 0800 27cf ce8e 0a00 0002  ........'.......
0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0a00 0001                 ..........
```

but in the destination machine:

```
20:03:29.114928 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.0.0.1 tell 10.0.0.2, length 46
0x0000:  0800 27bb f251 0800 27cf ce8e 0806 0001  ..'..Q..'.......
0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 0800 27cf ce8e 0a00 0002  ........'.......
0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0a00 0001 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............
```

Why the packet is zerofilled reaching a length of 46?

Answer (score 0):

The ARP message itself is 28 bytes long, exactly as you indicated. Now, with correct Ethernet implementations, the outgoing frame has to be padded to be at least 64 bytes long. There are some quirks about this, however - the device that originated this ARP message may itself be capable of sending it in an untagged frame or in 802.1Q-tagged frame. The tag size is always accounted towards the total frame size, resulting in different paddings: